# How to get SQL to update my record Modified Timestamp correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1293

I am trying to set up an sql table which records when an account was created and when it was last modified. I would like sql to handle this so I don't have to do it in my php files.

I have two columns in my users table (both are of type `timestamp`):

> created
>
> modified

I want the "created" time to never change and always contain the date it was created, and the "modified" to be changed each time the users row is modified. I have the table set up so "created" works as I expect, but when I try to update modified:

```
ALTER TABLE `users` 
   CHANGE `modified` `modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL 
   DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I get the following error:

> 1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

Can someone assist me on what I need to do to accomplish this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stil not possible in mysql. You can have them set to the actual time only on `INSERTs`, only on `UPDATEs` or on both. However you couldn't have more than one of these auto-TIMESTAMP columns in one table. that's now possible using `TRIGGERs` if using `Mysql 5.x`

Refer this article It will help you lot :

[Two auto-TIMESTAMP columns in one table with MySQL 5.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20120418112615/http://www.terrencemiao.com/Webmail/msg00949.html)

Comment: Same error: #1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause